# postgres Select all strings linked by foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like

```
select * from users where user_id = 10
```

How do I select all the data associated with this user on the foreign key, help make a request.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
   select u.*,ft.* from users u join foreign_table ft on u.user_id=ft.user_id
   where u.user_id=ft.user_id
```

here i assume `foreign_table` is your another table name where user_id is foreign key